# Sending failed while sending files using bluetooth on Android device

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

I am facing a problem when I send files using `Bluetooth` on my android phone, it transfers files upto 10% and then it shows sending failed.
I can't figure out the problem with `Bluetooth`.

Here is the logcat if anyone can help me fixing this error:

```
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): btlif_ctrl_callback: btlif_ctrl_callback : msg id BTLIF_
BTS_RFC_CON_RSP
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): btsk_bta_add: success (tot 1)
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bta_conns: bta conn : 3, blz 55, pid 5734, lst -1
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): btlif_signal_event: btsk 0x22a5118, event BTLIF_BTS_RFC_
CON_RSP
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bsock: btlif_signal_event [rfcomm] listen_fd: -1, p
ort 0, bta_srv -1, wsock: 55, rc: 9, wflags: 0x2304
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bta_conns: bta conn : 3, blz 55, pid 5734, lst -1
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): bts_dump_waitevents: btsk 0x22a5118 wait events: |BTLIF_
BTS_RFC_CON_RSP|BTLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND|
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): btlif_signal_event: wait events |BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_RSP|B
TLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND|
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): bts_event_to_flag: evt: 4487(BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_RSP), bit
no: 8, flag: 256
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): BTS_WAITFLAG_ISSET: btsk 0x22a5118, event 4487(BTLIF_BTS
_RFC_CON_RSP), isset 1, btsk->btlif_wait_flags 0x900, flag 0x100
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): btlif_signal_event: event BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_RSP matched
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): bts_event_to_flag: evt: 4487(BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_RSP), bit
no: 8, flag: 256
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): bts_event_to_flag: evt: 4487(BTLIF_BTS_RFC_CON_RSP), bit
no: 8, flag: 256
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bsock: unblocked [rfcomm] listen_fd: -1, port 0, bt
a_srv -1, wsock: 55, rc: 9, wflags: 0x0
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bta_conns: bta conn : 3, blz 55, pid 5734, lst -1
D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 5734): wrp_sock_connect: wrp_sock_connect brcm.bt.btlif:9051 (55)

D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 5734): wrp_sock_connect: BTLIF_MAKE_LOCAL_SERVER_NAME return name
: brcm.bt.btlif.9051
D/BTL_IFC_WRP( 5734): wrp_sock_connect: result 0, server name:brcm.bt.btlif.9051

I/BTL_IFC_WRP( 5734): wrp_sock_connect: Connected. (55)
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): __poll_rfc_connect: connection success
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): blz20_wrp_poll: poll done, result 0
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bsock: getsockopt [rfcomm] listen_fd: -1, port 9051
, bta_srv -1, wsock: 55, rc: 9, wflags: 0x0
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): dump_bta_conns: bta conn : 3, blz 55, pid 5734, lst -1
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): blz20_wrp_getsockopt: fetch errno 0
I/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): blz20_wrp_getsockopt: success
I/        ( 5311): check_listener_sock: check_listener 2276af0 (-1, listen 27)
I/        ( 5311): check_listener_sock: [DATA] Incoming connection on [brcm.bt.b
tlif] (27)
D/        ( 5311): wrp_data_accept: s:27
D/        ( 5311): wrp_data_accept: accepted 28
I/        ( 5311): wrp_data_accept: [DATA] Connected (28) [brcm.bt.btlif]
I/        ( 5311): btl_if_notify_local_event: Notify local event BTLIF_DATA_CHAN
_IND
I/        ( 5311): btlif_bts_api_ctrl_cb: id BTLIF_DATA_CHAN_IND (4110) on hdl 2
5
I/        ( 5311): dump_bta:     [data channel connected] bta handle : 3, blz 55
, dhdl 28, bd [2ccc15ac6cf3]
W/        ( 5311): SOCKET RX SIZE 4008 (4X mtu)
D/        ( 5311): bts_chan_dump_all: =================== all bts channels =====
================
D/        ( 5311): dump_chan:  (SCO) ctrl 24, port 9233, lstpnd 0, listen 129, b
ta cnt 1
I/        ( 5311): dump_bta:                    bta : 0, blz 129, dhdl -1, bd [0
00000000000]
D/        ( 5311): dump_chan:  (rfcomm) ctrl 25, port 9049, scn 12, phdl 65535,
lstpnd 0, pid 5734, listen 63, bta cnt 1
I/        ( 5311): dump_bta:                    bta : 1, blz -1, dhdl -1, bd [00
0000000000]
D/        ( 5311): dump_chan:  (rfcomm) ctrl 25, port 9050, scn 19, phdl 65535,
lstpnd 0, pid 5734, listen 58, bta cnt 1
I/        ( 5311): dump_bta:                    bta : 2, blz -1, dhdl -1, bd [00
0000000000]
D/        ( 5311): dump_chan:  (rfcomm) ctrl 25, port 9051, scn 9, phdl 14, lstp
nd 0, pid 5734, listen -1, bta cnt 1
I/        ( 5311): dump_bta:                    bta : 3, blz 55, dhdl 28, bd [2c
cc15ac6cf3]
D/        ( 5311): bts_chan_dump_all: ==========================================
=================
W/        ( 5311): tput rx:0, tx:0 (kB/s)  (tot : rx 0, tx 7 bytes)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:0 (kbps)
D/dalvikvm(  971): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1547K, 21% free 7946K/10019K, paused 2ms+
10ms
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:832 (kbps)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:882 (kbps)
D/dalvikvm( 5734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1856K, 38% free 3481K/5539K, paused 10ms+
6ms
D/BluetoothSocket( 5734): socket already in closing state:android.bluetooth.Blue
toothSocket@40dc3a30
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:983 (kbps)
W/        ( 5311): tput rx:0, tx:123 (kB/s)  (tot : rx 16, tx 249517 bytes)
I/USERIAL_LINUX( 5311): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Sleep, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_DEASSE
RT ####
D/WifiService(  358): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=
android.os.BinderProxy@41766ed8}
D/WifiService(  358): updateWifiState(): disable hotspot
D/WifiService(  358): updateWifiState(): disable wifi
V/BufferedAnalyticsState( 1346): Not ready for upload, 540 seconds left.
D/WifiService(  358): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=
android.os.BinderProxy@41766ed8}
D/WifiService(  358): updateWifiState(): disable hotspot
D/WifiService(  358): updateWifiState(): disable wifi
D/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 1346): DB info: open db, path = /data/data/com.google.andro
id.gms/databases , key = cgkve[ulv[UlvLkgYtakj, flag = 6, file size = 44032
D/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 1346): DB info: path = /data/data/com.google.android.gms/da
tabases , key = cgkve[ulv[UlvLkgYtakj, handle: 0x1fb66f0, type: w, r/w: (0,1), m
ode: truncate, disk free size: 433 M
D/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 1346): DB info: close db, path = /data/data/com.google.andr
oid.gms/databases , key = cgkve[ulv[UlvLkgYtakj, handle = 0x1fb66f0, type = w, r
/w = (0, 0)
I/GCoreUlr( 1346): Successfully inserted location
I/GCoreUlr( 1346): Not calling LocationReportingService, hasMoved: false, elapse
d millis: 420581, request: Phone
W/        ( 5311): tput rx:0, tx:22 (kB/s)  (tot : rx 22, tx 322291 bytes)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:286 (kbps)
D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(  971): isCdma():false hasService:true mSimState=UNKNOWN
gprsState=0 mDataState=-1 dataActivity=0 mPhone.htcModemLinkOn:false hspa==true
D/dalvikvm( 5734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1723K, 38% free 3486K/5539K, paused 2ms+3
ms
I/USERIAL_LINUX( 5311): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Wake, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_ASSERT
####
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:1012 (kbps)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:720 (kbps)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:1503 (kbps)
D/dalvikvm( 5734): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1930K, 43% free 3182K/5539K, paused 33ms
W/        ( 5311): tput rx:0, tx:134 (kB/s)  (tot : rx 34, tx 600263 bytes)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:1454 (kbps)
D/dalvikvm( 5734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1612K, 40% free 3359K/5539K, paused 16ms+
3ms
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:1430 (kbps)
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088484208) ##
# #####
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [0] task name [HCI] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [1] task name [BTU] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [2] task name [APPL] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [3] task name [SBC] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [4] task name [AVR] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [5] task name [PBS] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311):
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): * GKI_exception(): 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf done
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: bts_tx_buffer_done : tx que
ue empty #####
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088502320) ##
# #####
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088493264) ##
# #####
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [0] task name [HCI] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [1] task name [BTU] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [2] task name [APPL] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [3] task name [SBC] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [4] task name [AVR] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [5] task name [PBS] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311):
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): * GKI_exception(): 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf done
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088769472) ##
# #####
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [0] task name [HCI] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [1] task name [BTU] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [2] task name [APPL] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [3] task name [SBC] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [4] task name [AVR] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [5] task name [PBS] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311):
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): * GKI_exception(): 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf done
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088665328) ##
# #####
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [0] task name [HCI] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [1] task name [BTU] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [2] task name [APPL] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [3] task name [SBC] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [4] task name [AVR] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [5] task name [PBS] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311):
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): * GKI_exception(): 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf done
E/        ( 5311): ##### ERROR : bts_tx_buffer_done: ### ASSERT : ../../../Proje
cts/btl-a/adaptation/btapp/btapp_bts.c line 1715 buffer mismatch (1088891728) ##
# #####
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception(): Task State Table
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [0] task name [HCI] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [1] task name [BTU] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [2] task name [APPL] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [3] task name [SBC] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [4] task name [AVR] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): TASK ID [5] task name [PBS] state [1]
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311):
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): * GKI_exception(): 65532 Freeing Linked Buf
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): ************************************************************
********
I/GKI_LINUX( 5311): GKI_exception 65532 Freeing Linked Buf done
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:1559 (kbps)
D/dalvikvm( 5734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1601K, 38% free 3485K/5539K, paused 3ms+1
9ms
W/        ( 5311): tput rx:0, tx:178 (kB/s)  (tot : rx 52, tx 970729 bytes)
D/BLZ20_WRAPPER( 5734): tput_mon: s:55, rx:0, tx:831 (kbps)
I/BtOpp ObexClient( 5734): SendFile interrupted when send out file VID-20140325-
WA0000.mp4 at 966555 of 4903618
D/dalvikvm(  358): GC_EXPLICIT freed 424K, 22% free 12704K/16163K, paused 8ms+18
ms
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(  109): <CreateImage:813>: Android Image
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(  109): <GetImageAttributes:1022>: RGBA_8888
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightne
ss errno: 2
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/amber/blink er
rno: 2
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_time
r errno: 2
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/green/brightne
ss errno: 2
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/green/blink er
rno: 2
E/lights  (  358): [LedErr] open attr failed name=/sys/class/leds/green/off_time
r errno: 2
V/NotificationService(  358): Charging...
I/ActivityManager(  358): Start proc com.android.htccontacts for broadcast com.a
ndroid.htccontacts/.NotificationRemoveBroadcastReceiver: pid=6567 uid=10027 gids
={3003, 1015}
I/USERIAL_LINUX( 5311): ##### USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Sleep, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_DEASSE
RT ####
```

Comment: Please post the revelant code and your stacktrace inside your post.

Comment: You need to post some source code if you are interested in an answer. For one thing: What Bluetooth API did you use to transfer the data? RFCOMM, BLE or something else?